# Oracle Recursive Query - Dates

Tags: oracle

I've got two sets of dates being passed into a query and I would like to find all the months/years between both sets of dates.

When I try this:

```
WITH CTE_Dates (cte_date)  AS (
    SELECT cast(date '2014-01-27' as date)  from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cast(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'),1) as date)
    FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE ( TO_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'), 1)) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('27-01-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE ('27-04-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'))
        OR
          ( TO_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'), 1)) BETWEEN TRUNC(TO_DATE('27-11-2014','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MONTH')  AND TO_DATE ('27-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'))
      )
SELECT * from CTE_Dates
```

I get:

```
27-JAN-14
01-FEB-14
01-MAR-14
01-APR-14
```

I would also want to get:

```
01-NOV-14
01-DEC-14
01-JAN-15
```

It looks like the OR portion of the WHERE clause gets ignored.

Suggestions on how to create this query?

Thanks
Cory

Comment: so you have two sets of ranges?  will they ever overlap?

Comment: Yes, two set of ranges and they could potentially overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with what you have now (aside from extra `cast()` and `to_date()` calls) is that on the fourth iteration both the conditions are false so the recursion stops; there's nothing to make it skip a bit and pick up again, otherwise it would continue forever. I don't think you can achieve both ranges within the recursion.

You can put the latest date you want inside the recursive part, and then filter the two ranges you want afterwards:

```
WITH CTE_Dates (cte_date)  AS (
    SELECT date '2014-01-27'  from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'), 1)
    FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'), 1) <= date '2015-01-27'
)
SELECT * from CTE_Dates
WHERE cte_date BETWEEN date '2014-01-27' AND date '2014-04-27'
OR cte_date BETWEEN date '2014-11-27' AND date '2015-01-27';

CTE_DATE 
---------
27-JAN-14 
01-FEB-14 
01-MAR-14 
01-APR-14 
01-DEC-14 
01-JAN-15 

 6 rows selected
```

You can replace the hard-coded values with your pairs of start and end dates. If the ranges might overlap or the second range could be (or end) before the first one, you could pick the higher date:

```
    WHERE ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(cte_date, 'MONTH'), 1)
      <= greatest(date '2015-01-27', date '2014-04-27')
```

... though that only makes sense with variables, not fixed values.

Comment: Thank you, I have the extra cast becasue if I don't cast then I get ORA-01790: expression must have same dataytpe as corresponding expression

Comment: This works for me as shown; but maybe your real version is passing in timestamps rather than dates, which would then need to be cast. You shouldn't need to cast either `add_months()` call though.