# How to add missing months in each year in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the output from my query

[image]

but I need all months in 2016 and 2017 in the output means

01-2017,02-2017,03-2017,04-2017,05-2017, 06-2017, 07-2017, 08-2017,09-2017,10-2017,11-2017,12-2017,01-2016,01-2016,01-2016,02-2016,03-2016,04-2016,05-2016,06-2016,07-2016,08-2016,09-2016,10-2016,11-2016,12-2016]

my query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    to_char(to_date(checked_date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm-yyyy') AS month
FROM DOCTOR_CHECKUP;
```

The below image shows the output of my query, but I need all months in 2016 and 2017 in the output means 01-2017,02-2017,03-2017,04-2017,05-2017, 06-2017, 07-2017, 08-2017,09-2017,10-2017,11-2017,12-2017,01-2016,01-2016,01-2016,02-2016,03-2016,04-2016,05-2016,06-2016,07-2016,08-2016,09-2016,10-2016,11-2016,12-2016

Comment: is it mysql or oracle ?

Comment: Not mysql, it is oracle

Comment: this is a duplicate question then 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates

Comment: I am not getting what they have explained in above link.

Comment: like the answers below, you either use a cte to produce the days or a derived table and left join.

Comment: here is another example 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178484/oracle-recursive-query-dates

Comment: Thank you for deleting your follow up question to this post. I was working on an answer for you. That's a chunk of my life I won't get back. The reason why we dislike screenshots is precisely because it takes us longer to create working examples of solutions when we have to write the DDL and DML statements ourselves. In future please respect the strangers you are asking to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. Obviously you don't even need the table when you simply want to select months from `'01-2016'` to `'12-2017'`:

```
select '01-2016' as month from dual
union all
select '02-2016' as month from dual
union all
...
union all
select '12-2017' as month from dual
```

Comment: here, what is meant by "dual"?

Comment: `DUAL` is oracle's dummy table, so you can "make up" values out of nothing. You can read about it here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm

Comment: It's a built-in table in Oracle with only one record. This is needed, because Oracle always requires a table name to query from (several other DBMS are fine with a mere `select '01-2016' as month`).

Answer (score 1):

This query generates 24 *"month"* values:

```
select to_char(add_months(date '2016-01-01', level - 1), 'mm-yyyy') mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24
```

... and this is basic answer. If You want to find missing months You can `minus` this query and Yours:

```
select to_char(add_months(date '2016-01-01', level - 1), 'mm-yyyy') mth 
  from dual connect by level <= 24
minus
select to_char(to_date(checked_date, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'mm-yyyy')
  from doctor_checkup
```

It's similiar to David Faber's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634180/oracle-sql-fill-in-missing-dates), I added `add_months` and second part to answer this particular question.

Looks like `checked_date` is varchar type, You should avoid storing dates in such format.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table or a fixed date table (which is more recommended) , like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(t.month_col,s.month) as month_col
FROM(
    SELECT '01-2016' as month_col FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '02-2016' as month_col FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL 
    .... // all the dates you want
     ) t
LEFT JOIN YourTable s
```

Though it seems unnecessary here, if you're not using any extra info from your table, just use the inner query of `t` alias .

Answer (score 0):

Use the query provided by Ponder Stibbons

```
select to_char(add_months(date '2016-01-01', level - 1), 'mm-yyyy') mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24
```

Then you can join this to your table to get any required stats related to the doctor_checkup. Note that the join should be on the month of the checked_date in your "doctor_checkup". You might want to create a function-based index: to_char(checked_date, 'mm-yyyy')

For example, to get the number of appointments per month

```
select mth, nvl(count(1), 0) appointments
from (select to_char(add_months(date '2016-01-01', level - 1), 'mm-yyyy') mth 
      from dual 
      connect by level <= 24) mo 
      left outer join doctor_checkup dc on mo.mth = to_char(dc.checked_date, 'mm-yyyy')
```