# Oracle 10g: selecting n date from dual with format YYYY-MM

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to display 12 month from 5 years back March.
The only way I can get it right is with:

```
select to_char(add_months(sysdate, level-51),'YYYY-MM') 
from dual 
connect by level <= 12
```

Which display:

```
2014-03
2014-04
2014-05
...
```

However I need a date.

But trying using:

```
select to_date(to_char(add_months(sysdate, level-51),'YYYY-MM'),'YYYY-MM') 
from dual 
connect by level <= 12
```

Give the months:

```
2014-03-01
2014-04-01
2014-05-01
...
```

**Question**
Does someone have a solution ?

EDIT:

Doing

```
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM';
```

Fix the problem but how can set this format in a stored procedure ?

Comment: So you want to get date type in output, and display them in format 'YYYY-MM'? IMO you should do that formatting in your presentation layer (front-end, application), because whatever format you do in your database, the output you get in your application will be datetime, which may have default display format differ from your database.

Comment: Its related to this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476162/oracle-10g-inserting-missing-dates-for-table-with-others-values Now I have the solution of this problem, but it will work only if I can transform YYYY-MM-DD into YYYY-MM.

Comment: For your previous problem, you should do a `CROSS JOIN` using your calendar table and your distinct EID, instead of a for loop. And why do you care about format a datetime type when you try inserting to a table? After inserting, it's just a datetime type, and will have all part: year, month, day, hour, minute, secs. Search and read more about oracle DATE data type. So you only need `SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, LEVEL-51), 'MM') FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12`

Comment: Thanks. Found indeed a solution around your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply truncate the resulting values:

```
select trunc(add_months(sysdate, level-51), 'MM')
from dual
connect by level <= 12
```

Comment: Thanks. How will this command look like if the sysdate were a string? For e.g. ''2014-05' won't work. Is there a way to avoid having to enter the full date string (with time) ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange . . . I don't understand the question.  `sysdate` is a date.  You should use a date for this method.  If you have a string, convert it to a date.